# Flask project setup - local class lib

Tags: python, flask

- the dir with the needed import is in PYTHONPATH
- I've put a print in the top of **init**.py

   import sys

   print(sys.path) 

   and all is well - see 3rd line of code below
- the dir with the needed import is in PYTHONPATH
- I've put a print in the top of **init**.py

   import sys

   print(sys.path) 

   and all is well

Here's the folder structure:
dgl-home
--dglLib  # the class lib that's not being found; has **init**.py 
--dgl-env   # pipenv venv
--flask-projects
----learn   # the project in question

Here's console:

    `(dgl-env-nWAMFiVe) (xenial)les@localhost:~/dgl-home/dgl-env/flask- 
    projects/learn$ python run.py
    sys.path ['/home/les/dgl-home/dgl-env/flask-projects/learn', 
    '/home/les/dgl-home/dgl-env/dglLib', 
    '/home/les/.local/share/virtualenvs/dgl-env- 
    nWAMFiVe/lib/python36.zip', '/home/les/.local/share/virtualenvs/dgl- 
    env-nWAMFiVe/lib/python3.6', '/home/les/.local/share/virtualenvs/dgl- 
    env-nWAMFiVe/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload', '/usr/lib/python3.6', 
    '/home/les/.local/share/virtualenvs/dgl-env- 
    nWAMFiVe/lib/python3.6/site-packages']
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "run.py", line 1, in 
        from learn import app
     File "/home/les/dgl-home/dgl-env/flask- 
   projects/learn/learn/init.py", line 8, in 
    from dglLib import (
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dglLib'
    (dgl-env-nWAMFiVe) (xenial)les@localhost:~/dgl-home/dgl-env/flask- 
   projects/learn$ ls -alt /home/les/dgl-home/dgl-env/dglLib
    total 72
    drwxr-xr-x 7 les root  4096 Jun 20 18:07 ..
    drwxr-xr-x 3 les les   4096 Jun 20 17:34 .
    -rw-rw-r-- 1 les les      0 Jun 20 17:34 init.py
    drwxrwxr-x 8 les les   4096 Jun 20 17:23 .git
    -rw-rw-r-- 1 les les   4315 Jun 12 19:13 dglPickleToS3BucketClasses.py
    -rw-rw-r-- 1 les les  10487 Jun 12 19:07 dglContactsClasses.py
    -rw-rw-r-- 1 les les   3343 Jun 11 17:38 gaicClasses.html
    -rw-rw-r-- 1 les les   5713 Jun 11 17:32 
    dglPickleToS3BucketClasses.html
    -rw-rw-r-- 1 les les  22042 Jun 11 17:23 dglContactsClasses.html
    -rw-rw-r-- 1 les les    784 Jun 10 00:24 gaicClasses.py`

Comment: Please format your question

Comment: Forgot one thing - atom, running in the venv - sees dglLib just fine

Comment: Saw comment "Please format your question – user3483203" - I thought I did????

Comment: Found it - https://python-notes.curiousefficiency.org/en/latest/python_concepts/import_traps.html#the-double-import-trap - I put full path on PYTHONPATH - including the dir with the class defs - had to backup one level

Answer (score 0):

Found it -

https://python-notes.curiousefficiency.org/en/latest/python_concepts/import_traps.html#the-double-import-trap -

- I put full path on PYTHONPATH - including the dir with the class defs - had to backup one level